# Is there a way to get the column number by column name in jqgrid

Tags: jquery-plugins, jqgrid

I tried to access the rowObject in custom formatter function by column name but it didn't give any values. I have tried this with both JSON and XML data type .

Is there any way to get the column number by column name in jqgrid.

```
function Draw_Link ( cellvalue , options , rowObject )
 { 
  return "<a href='someurl.php?col_name="+rowobject.col_name+"'>"+cellvalue+"</a>";
 }
```

Answer (score 12):

The column index for the column is the same as the index of the column in the `colModel` array **before** the jqGrid initialization (it is the same as in the input parameter `colModel`). If you use `rownumbers:true`, `multiselect:true` or `subGrid:true` additional columns will be addid to the grid as the first rows, so the column index which one has in the `colModel` array as the jqGrid parameter can be other as one have after the grid initialization. You can use for example this simple function to get the index

```
var getColumnSrcIndexByName = function(grid,columnName) {
    var cm = grid.jqGrid('getGridParam','colModel'),
        i=0, index=0, l=cm.length, cmName;
    while (i<l) {
        cmName = cm[i].name;
        i++;
        if (cmName===columnName) {
            return index;
        } else if (cmName!=='rn' && cmName!=='cb' && cmName!=='subgrid') {
            index++;
        }
    }
    return -1;
};
var index = getColumnSrcIndexByName($("#list"),'MyColumn');
```

**UPDATED:** [Free jqGrid](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid) fork simplifies getting column index from column name because it holds internally the parameter `iColByName`, which is the map by the column name. One can just get `iColByName` via

```
var iColByName = $("#list").jqGrid("getGridParam", "iColByName");
```

and `iColByName["MyColumn"]` will be the required column index (`iCol`). I remind that one can use `getGridParam` without any parameter to get the reference to *all* parameters of jqGrid:

```
var p = $("#list").jqGrid("getGridParam");
```

The value

```
var iCol = p.iColByName["MyColumn"];
```

will be the column index and `p.colModel[iCol].name` will be `"MyColumn"`.